# Find text between two characters and for each, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file full with text in the following format:
(ignoring the fact that it is CSS) I need to get the string between the two | characters and each time, do something:

```
<div id="unused">
  |#main|
  #header|
  .bananas|
  #nav|
  etc
</div>
```

The code I have is this:

```
var test_str = $('#unused').text();
var start_pos = test_str.indexOf('|') + 1;
var end_pos = test_str.indexOf('|',start_pos);
var text_to_get = test_str.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
//I want to do something with each string here
```

This just gets the first string. How can I add logic in there to do something for each string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split method to get array of strings between `|`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ucCbY/)**

```
arr = $('#unused').text().split('|');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split like

```
var my_splitted_var = $('#unused').text().split('|');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way;

```
$.each($("#unused").text().split("|"), function(ix, val) {
    val = $.trim(val); //remove \r|\n
    if (val !== "")
        alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way :

```
    var test_str = $('#unused').text();

while(!test_str.indexOf('|'))
{
var start_pos = test_str.indexOf('|') + 1;
var end_pos = test_str.indexOf('|',start_pos);
var text_to_get = test_str.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
test_str  = test_str.slice(end_pos,test_str.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RegExp-Version:

**[LIVE DEMO (jsfiddle.net)](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj9LT/)**

```
var trimmedHtml = $("#unused").html().replace(/\s/g, '');

var result = new Array();

var regExp = /\|(.+?)(?=\|)/g;
var match = regExp.exec(trimmedHtml);
result.push(match[1]);
while (match != null) {
    match = regExp.exec(trimmedHtml);
    if (match != null) result.push(match[1]);
}

alert(result);
```

So you only get the elements BETWEEN the pipes (`|`).
In my example I pushed every matching result to an array. You can now iterate over it to get your result.